# Apache Pig How to whitelist or blacklist in Load function?

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I am wondering if it's possible to maintain a whitelist or blacklist in Pig's Load function. Say I am doing the following:

```
AllData = LOAD '/path/to/dir/CAT*' USING AvroStorage();
```

This would load all the files that starts with the CAT prefix.

```
e.g. CAT1, CAT2, CAT3, CAT4, CAT5, CAT6
```

I am wondering if it's possible to maintain a blacklist to filter out let's say `CAT2, CAT3` or to maintain a whitelist that keeps `CAT1, CAT4, CAT5, CAT6` only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a whitelist by listing all the filename suffixes in curly brackets, like:

```
AllData = LOAD '/path/to/dir/CAT{1,4,5,6}' USING AvroStorage();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ideally, I want to blacklist because there's thousands of valid path but very few invalid ones.

Comment: There may be a way to blacklist in the load statement, but I don't know how. One option is to load all files, load the blacklist, outer join the 2 relations, and filter out the records that appear in both.